# hey guys I try to upload a generated apk to google play store and keep getting this error any ideas

Tags: android, store, playback

I try to upload a generated apk to google play store and keep getting this error any ideas

[image]

Comment: have you signed your apk? Refer [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing) for more info.

Comment: Explain the steps how you generated your APK file.

Comment: Follow the steps before uploading to playstore : check the apk in the checking device.If it is fine ok otherwise your apk is not correct.

Comment: Is there any YouTube video can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Create a release apk of your app. You can follow the steps when creating from official [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing). Make sure you have incremented the version codes as well when you are updating the store listing. Keep your keystore file somewhere safe so that you will not risk losing it. Losing it means losing your app (un updatable) in playstore.

Comment: Metasnarf can you explain more?